# React: moving to a particular child component of my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a callback function which receives an argument from child component(here CardTiles) and it is processed and passed as props to another child component. The output is displayed correctly but I have to move my page to that particular section(the second child component-OutputWindow). How can i trigger an anchor tag from my 1st child component? or would refs work here?
Child component 1:

```html
<CardTiles  parentCallback={handleCallback}/>
```

Child component 2:

```html
<OutputWindow name={place}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or would refs work here

Yes. Have a ref in the parent, put it on the child (`ref={theRef}`), have the child forward that ref to the outermost (probably) HTML element it renders, and then in the callback function have the code use `theRef.current?.scrollIntoView()`¹ to scroll that element into view.

More

- [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
- [Forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)
- [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

---

¹ That's using optional chaining, which is fairly new. If your project isn't set up for it, you can use `if (theRef.current) { theRef.current.scrollIntoView(); }` instead.